# Can't view forms and queries in MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016

We are doing an MS Access to Oracle conversion and I am on step one: Researching and capturing all the forms, queries, and the rest of the table definitions in Access. I have transferred both the main and split database (.accdb) to my local drive. However, I am unable to view or open the forms and most of the queries in Access because they reside in a folder on a shared drive that I do not have permission to.

Instead of giving me permission, the directions given to me:

**You have to change the pointer in access to point to where you put the file on your hard drive**. (Where I transferred both the main/split DBs)

I have no earthly idea how to go about this and it's embarrassing. Will anyone please elaborate on how to do this in Access?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have a split MS Access database, consisting of a front end (FE.accdb) containing the queries, forms, reports and modules (and possibly some static tables), and a back end (BE.accdb) containing the tables.

Now that you have moved both of these files away from the "live" environment, the front end can no longer see the original back end, as it is stored in a place where you don't have permissions to access it, and you need to point it to your local copy of the back end.

If this is the case, open the front end, and select "External Data" from the menu at the top of Access. Then select "Linked Table Manager", which will bring up a screen like the one below:

[image]

Click on "Select All", and then "Relink". Choose the location of your copy of the back end, and click "Open" to start relinking.

Regards,

Comment: This is working! It's making me go one by one but that's fine by me. Thank you for taking the time to point that out to me, my lead isn't very helpful. Didn't realize it was right in front of me this whole time.

Comment: @mookie_bombs just popped over to review a question from a new user and wanted to remind you: since you asked the question, if it's working don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (helps other users searching to identify effective solutions and gives credit where it's due)

Comment: More info here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @TheXenocide Stack wouldn't let me give it a vote up because I didn't have enough reputation. Is marking this as accepted the same as giving it a vote up?

Comment: @Applecore I realized that the Linked Table Manager isn't listing any forms or queries in the list of values, only the tables in both the front end and the back end. In other words, I don't see an option to relink any forms or queries.

Comment: You should be doing the re-linking from you copy of the FE, which should already have forms/queries/reports/modules in. It should only be tables in the BE that you are re-linking.

Comment: You should be doing the re-linking from you copy of the FE, which should already have forms/queries/reports/modules in. It should only be tables in the BE that you are re-linking.

Comment: @mookie_bombs marking it as the accepted answer is even better than voting it up, though if you had enough reputation I would generally recommend upvoting any good answer, but the main difference is that there can only be one accepted answer while you can (given enough reputation) upvote as many answers as you find helpful.

Comment: @Applecore I thought I was importing the forms/queries/reports/modules from the locked folder to the copy of the BE but I go through the process, save the import and I am still unable to view most of them. There are random forms I am able to open but thats it. I appreciate your help though, thank you.

Comment: @TheXenocide Good to know! I had no clue, thank you! :)